# MySQL Unmodifiable Column?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to declare that a column in MySQL should be unmodifiable once initially set? I have a column that has the following definition: `created timestamp default current_timestamp` and I'd like to make sure that nobody messes with it after my rows are created.

Comment: I'm no expert, but my guess would be to create a Trigger whenever the row is updated to check and see if that column was updated, and if so to intercept it and prevent its execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a [`BEFORE UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER trFoo BEFORE UPDATE ON foo
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      IF NEW.Bar != OLD.Bar THEN
        SET NEW.Bar = OLD.Bar;      
      END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Dastardly. I was hoping that there would be an actual SQL constraint, but this also works.